# How to show relationships between tables in Data Modeler?

Tags: oracle

I have some Oracle Tables with foreign keys constraints but when I add them to Data Modeler, the relationships between the tables don't show.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I do that please ?

Comment: Is there a table country on your model? Because the table reference shows the location_country but the associations is with COUNTRY table that is not on the image you posted

Comment: In the table MARK_MARKETS I have a field called Country which is linked to the ID of a table named LOCATION_COUNTRY. That's what is shown in the picture. Sorry it's in french !

Comment: Drag and drop from one table to the other with the middle button of your mouse.

Comment: I did it but it's not working. It's just selecting the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using RSA (Rational Software Architect) for Data Modelling. First Load the tables in RSA from the database.Then you just need to do drag and drop the tables which needs in the data model. After this select all, right click on the screen and select format -> arrange -> auto. This will give you all the relationships between the tables.